# Aerofoil study using CFD, struggling to find aerofoil coordinates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, computational-geometry, openfoam, ansys-fluent

I’ve been messing around with Ansys and I’m struggling to find the aerofoil coordinates for a NACA 66-012?

I looked on Airfoil tools, but it doesn’t allow you to generate a 6 series aerofoil, only 4 and 5.

Does anyone know any resource that can generate a 66-012 or any 6 series aerofoil coordinates please?

Comment: Airfoil does have this selection http://airfoiltools.com/search/index?m%5Bgrp%5D=naca6 which says it's 6-series.

Answer (score 1):

The NACA 6 series is obtained by conformal transformation (starting from a circle, you can find a reference [here](https://evoq-eval.siam.org/Portals/0/Publications/SIURO/Vol1_Issue2/Modeling_the_Fluid_Flow.pdf?ver=2018-04-02-120817-147) for example, but there are plenty), so there is not an easy and straight forward analystical formulation as for 4 digit and 5 digit profiles.

You can still generate your data in [airfoil tool](https://airfoiltools.com/search/index?m%5Bgrp%5D=naca6).

If you are not sure about results, you can find valuable information in the old, but still good, [pdas website](https://www.pdas.com/). In particular the resource you are searching is [here](https://www.pdas.com/avd.pdf) or in a more "interactive" way [here](https://www.pdas.com/sections6.html). Otherwise you can refer to the "bible" of airfoil data: the [Abbott report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930090976). There you will find the distribution of thickness of all the airfoils of NACA and GA series.